# Twitter Bootstrap's accordion and multiple children

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

How to expand/show multiple children? Currently Service2 is not shown.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion1">
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <div class="accordion-toggle group-accordion-toggle">
            <a href="#collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion1"
               data-toggle="collapse" class=""><i
                    class="icon-plus"></i></a>
            <a href="http://www.example.com">Operator</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner"><a
                href="http://www.example.com/service1">Service1</a></div>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner"><a
                href="http://www.example.com/service2">Service2</a></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mejo/CXDC8/

Comment: I suppose that Bootstrap's accordion does not support what I'm looking for?

Comment: Solution could be simply accordion class inside first accordion, so nesting whole accordion structure where needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just remove the `<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">` container from `Section2`?

```
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">

        <div class="accordion-inner"><a
                href="http://www.example.com/service1">Service1</a>
        </div>

        <div class="accordion-inner"><a
                href="http://www.example.com/service2">Service2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SiCurious/CXDC8/2/) illustrating what I mean.

Also, it's bad practice to have two elements with same ID, and may cause issues further down the road.